# Fluent NHibernate One-to-many with 3 classes

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 3 classes and their mappings and each of them has reference to the previous like:

A -> B -> C

A can have C but only if B got C(due to its impossible A -> C)

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string messageA {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<B> Bs {get;set;}
}


class B
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string messageB {get;set;}
    public virtual A A {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<C> Cs {get;set;}
}

class C
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string messageC {get;set;}
    public virtual B B{get;set;}
}

//Mappings

class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.messageA);
        HasMany(x => x.Bs);
    }   
}

class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.messageB);
        References(x => x.A).Cascade.All();
        HasMany(x => x.Cs);
    }   
}

class CMap : ClassMap<C>
{
    public CMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.messageC);
        References(x => x.B).Cascade.All();
    }   
}
```

I got such an error while trying to commit:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to
>   something that would make it autosave. Type: NHibernateTest.C, Entity:
>   NHibernateTest.C.

I was looking for the solution, someone said I have to modify foreign key update rule into cascade, I did it and still not working.

I just want to mention that it was working with A -> B relation, when I added C the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such problems in future you should make sure that:

- All your classes are *public*
- Don't have circular references as in your example B->A, C->B

---

The following test case works as you expect (A->B->C).

**Model definitions:**

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string messageA { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string messageB { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string messageC { get; set; }
}
```

**Map definitions:**

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Table("A");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.messageA);
        HasMany(x => x.Bs).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Table("B");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id"); ;
        Map(x => x.messageB);
        HasMany(x => x.Cs).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class CMap : ClassMap<C>
{
    public CMap()
    {
        Table("C");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id"); ;
        Map(x => x.messageC);
    }
}
```

**NUnit test method:**

```
[Test]
public void ShouldCorrectlyMapA()
{
    var objectA = new A
    {
        Id = 1,
        messageA = "Message A",
        Bs = new List<B> { 
            new B
            {
                messageB = "Message B",
                Cs = new List<C>
                {
                    new C
                    {
                        messageC = "Message C"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    new PersistenceSpecification<A>(_session)
        .VerifyTheMappings(objectA);

}
```

**Using [in-memory SQLite](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing) unit test, the test runners output of**

**Schema creation:**

> ```
> create table A (
>     Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
>    messageA TEXT
> )
>
> create table B (
>     Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
>    messageB TEXT,
>    A_id INT,
>    constraint FKCDCAB7DE9EFDCD1D foreign key (A_id) references A
> )
>
> create table C (
>     Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
>    messageC TEXT,
>    B_id INT,
>    constraint FKCDCAB7DD3844B1E1 foreign key (B_id) references B
> )
> ```

**[DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) operations on the just created schema:**

> ```
> NHibernate: INSERT INTO A (messageA) VALUES (@p0); select last_insert_rowid();@p0 = 'Message A' [Type: String (0)]
> NHibernate: INSERT INTO B (messageB) VALUES (@p0); select last_insert_rowid();@p0 = 'Message B' [Type: String (0)]
> NHibernate: INSERT INTO C (messageC) VALUES (@p0); select last_insert_rowid();@p0 = 'Message C' [Type: String (0)]
> NHibernate: UPDATE B SET A_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
> NHibernate: UPDATE C SET B_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
> ```